# Proguard for SignalR Android

Tags: android, service, signalr, android-proguard

The code below works correctly in the debug version and the message is sent via mHubProxy.on (..) to the Client, but the message is not sent in the Release version. I used Proguard in the Release, and when Proguard is disabled, messages are received. Is there a problem with Proguard or in the code?

> in Service

```
private void StartSignalR() {       
      androidPlatformComponent = new AndroidPlatformComponent();
      Platform.loadPlatformComponent(androidPlatformComponent);
      Credentials credentials = new Credentials() {
                @Override
                public void prepareRequest(Request request) {
                    request.addHeader(Header, **));
                }
            };

            String serverUrl = "http://" + dataSaveApp.ServerAddress;
            mHubConnection = new HubConnection(serverUrl);
            mHubConnection.setCredentials(credentials);

            mHubProxy = mHubConnection.createHubProxy(SERVER_HUB_CHAT);
            ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mHubConnection.getLogger());
            connectAsyncSignalR = null;
            connectAsyncSignalR = new SignalRConnectAsync(mHubConnection);
            try {
                boolean isDone = connectAsyncSignalR.execute(clientTransport).get();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                stopService(intent);
                startService(intent);
                return;
            }

            //Not working in Release Version
            mHubProxy.on("sendData", new SubscriptionHandler1<String>() {
                @Override
                public void run(String msg) {
                    Log.d(Variable.TagMessage , msg);

                }
            }, String.class);
        }
    }

public static void SendMessage(String message) {
       mHubProxy.invoke(SendMessageServerMethod,message);
    }
```

> in Progaurd File

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
     @butterknife.* <fields>;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you get any solution?